# Pop of Color Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, black, white

I want to have the background be black and white and then a rectangle of color be normal but I don’t know how and when I erase it it’s shaky. What do I do.

Answer (score 1):

Add a black and white adjustment layer to a colour image, select the layer mask in the layers panel, make a selection using the Rectangle Select tool, and then do *Edit > Fill*, and choose black as the fill colour.

[image]

Comment: And I am the one encouraging people to ask fuzzy questions... XD